# More optimized way to solve for efficient inserts and lookups

Tags: java, algorithm, sorting, data-structures

There is a snippet below that I have. I have to implement `addTrade`
and `printTop`

```
 public static void main(String args[] ) throws Exception {
        MostTraded mt = new MostTraded();
        mt.addTrade("IBM",  1000);
        mt.addTrade("AAPL",  500);
        mt.addTrade("NFLX",  600);
        mt.addTrade("AAPL",  900);

        mt.printTop(2); // AAPL 1400, IBM 1000
    }
```

The signature for the two methods is as below:

```
public void addTrade(String instrument, int volume)
public void printTop(int count)
```

Argument to `printTop` implies print those many heavily traded stocks. For example `printTop(2)` will mean top 2 traded stocks. The adds have to be efficient which also means a stock can be traded multiple times in which case the `volume` needs to be updated.

I have the following thought to solve it but not sure if a better way is there.

To implement efficient addition of values for lookup and add for stock, I can use a simple `HashMap` with `<stockname, volume>` 
To do `printTop`, I can use `TreeMap` whose key is `volume` and value is a `Set<String>` to keep track. 
Clearly, when I do and `addTrade`, I will have to modify the entries in `TreeMap` as well.

Is there a better way to solve the same problem?

Comment: The best answer could depend on how the solution is expected to be used. I would think if Adds typically happen thousands of times between printTops, the best solution would be different than if there are only a few Adds between printTops.

Comment: @hatchet, you assumption is correct, the adds are way more frequent than printTop. And a certain amount of slowness for that is acceptable. Keeping your assumption is mind, what will be a more ideal solution?

Comment: Especially if the number of different tickers is smaller than the number of Adds that would be expected to happen between PrintTop calls, or the number of top items typically desired is small, then I'm guessing it would be cheaper to partially sort on demand (when PrintTop is called) as DodgyCodeException suggests than it would be to maintain an ordered collection. You would only maintain the HashMap. If you just want PrintTop to be as optimal as possible, and don't care so much about the maintenance cost distributed over the Adds, that suggests a different answer.

Comment: @hatchet, I will read about partial sorting. Given the fact that I want adds to be as fast as possible, are you suggesting, just use a hashmap for faster updates and maybe maintain a linkedlist or what which I can partially sort on the fly?

Comment: or just go over the full hashmap when it comes to printing and use minHeap to get topK elements to make it nlogK for printing?

Answer (score 0):

It depends on how much optimization you are looking for. If you are writing a real-time trading application, you'll want it to be as fast as possible. Maintaining a TreeMap of Sets of strings is not going to be very efficient. You only want to find the *top K* out of N items. Therefore you need a [partial sort algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partial_sorting). C++ already has a partial sort method as standard; unfortunately, Java hasn't. But you can find a third-party one online or write one yourself.